# Java Files changed to binary files

Tags: java, android

I am using Android studio for development. My project files changes to some binary format file I don't know how. And when I am trying to open them in Studio it is showing in binary format however it is opening properly in notepad.

You can see the green tick mark sign on the file. Every changed file showing same tick mark. At first, I thought it might be a virus, then when I saw only Android project files are affected. Anyone with some insight to it will be helpful.[image]

Files are looking like this.
[image]

You can see in the below image there are two type of file symbol showing. One is with 'j' and one with 'c'. Files with 'c' type showing normally whereas issue with 'j' type files. If I copy contain of the file from notepad and set the value inside Android studio editor then it is coming back to normal.
[image]

Comment: "Binary format"? What do you mean by that? The tick mark looks like some kind of source control system telling you that file is checked in (TortoiseGit or something like that). Odds are that something saved your files in a different encoding UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 or vice versa. But then again both Notepad++ and Android Studio should be capable of displaying both of those.

Comment: Notepad++ able to show it, however, I tried different encoding like UTF-8 for Android studio but it still showing in binary format.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "binary format". Post a screenshot if you can't explain it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Kindly see the edit.

Comment: It sounds like the file actually contains the byte code (normally residing in `BillUploadActivity.class`) and not your java source.

Comment: @Benoit not actually. I can see the java code in notepad editor.

Comment: @Kunu: then you are opening a different file from a different location. There's no way this content is opened "regularly" in another editor. Check the absolute file paths of the files you're opening in both editors. And yes, this looks indeed as if the class file has somehow been saved with a .java extension, which is pretty bad, something's gone awry.

Comment: What is more confusing is some files opening properly and some are not.

Comment: Can you attach one those "binary" file, so that we can check it ?

Comment: @Benoit One attachment already there in question. See the last image.

Comment: @JoachimSauer See the edit.

Comment: Sorry @Kunu but you attached a screenshot, I would like the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that **the file actually contain the byte code**, and not the source. This is not an encoding problem.

I have been able to reproduce the problem using IntelliJ (Android Studio is based on IntelliJ):

I created a simple class (under `src/main/java`):

```
public class IsBinaryOrNot {
}
```

- I compile it. I get `IsBinaryOrNot.class` under (under `target/classes`).
- I **rename** `IsBinaryOrNot.class` to `IsBinaryOrNot.java`.
- I open the renamed file in Intellij, and I get:

[image]

It really looks like what you get in Android Studio. As you can see, both files have a different icon, the original source has the 'c', while the renamed has a 'j' which is almost the same as you get.

Comment: Do you have any idea how class files changed to Java extension? And is there any way to revert back without manually changing each file?

Comment: @Kunu That's another story. Maybe you could post the `build.gradle`. I would suspect the error is there...